# Writing a vector space as the column or null space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following problem in my textbook that I am struggling with:

Is the given set $W$ a vector space. If possible express $W$ as the column or null space of some matrix $A$.

$W = \{\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\ 
y \\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}: 5x = y + 2z\}$

It seems to me that $W$ is in fact a vector space, however I am struggling to see how I can represent it as the column space or null space of a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging the equation $5x = y + 2z$, we see that $W$ is the set of vectors $(x,y,z)^T$ satisfying $5x -y - 2z = 0$ or, to put it in matrix form,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\ 
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus $W$ is the null space of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$